# Why does javascrip implemented in my website not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Script i implemented into my website doesn't work, i've checked everything and im going along a tutorial. Any ideas?

Link to my github repository:
https://github.com/DBvagabond/dbogdanski
link to webist preview:
https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/DBvagabond/dbogdanski/blob/main/index.html

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">

            <a class="logo" href="index.html"><span>d</span>bogdanski</a>

            <img id="mobile-cta" class="mobile-menu" src="images/menu1.svg" alt="menu">

            <nav>
            <img id="mobile-exit" class="mobile-menu-exit" src="images/exit1.svg" alt="exit">
                <ul class="primary-nav">
                    <li class="current"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="secondary-nav">
                    <li class="contact-cta"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="hero">
        hero
    </section>
    
    <script>
        const mobileBtn = document.getElementById('mobile-cta')
              nav = document.querySelector('nav')
              mobileBtnExit = document.getElementById('mobile-exit');

        mobileBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            nav.classList.add('menu-btn');
        })

        mobileBtnExit.addEventListener('click', () => {
            nav.classList.remove('menu-btn');
        }) 
    </script>

</body>
```

SCSS

```
.navbar {
    background: var(--primary-color);
    padding: 1em;

    .logo {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: var(--secondary-color);
        font-size: 1.2em;

            span {
                color: white;
            }
    }

    nav {
        display: none;
    }

    .mobile-menu{
        width: 1.5em;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .container {
        display: flex;
        place-content: space-between;
    }  
        
    .mobile-menu-exit{
        width: 1.5em;
        float: right;
        margin: .5em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section {
    padding: 5em 2em;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 66%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: grey;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 1em;

    ul.primary-nav {
        margin-top: 5em;
    }

    li {
        a{
            color: var(--secondary-color);
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            padding: .5em;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            text-align: right;

            &:hover {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked for the errors, copied and pasted code from the repository of author.
mobile menu should pop up and close upon clicking hamburger menu icon.

Comment: you toggling `menu-btn` class, but you not defined any .menu-btn CSS class

Answer (score 0):

Why is JavaScript not working on my website?
On the web browser menu click on the "Edit" and select "Preferences". In the "Preferences" window select the "Security" tab. In the "Security" tab section "Web content" mark the "Enable JavaScript" checkbox. Click on the "Reload the current page" button of the web browser to refresh the page.

Comment: a question is not an answer